# AverTV Trinity Card works on one motherboard, but doesn't work on newer

Tags: motherboard

I have an AverTV Satellite Trinity TV tuner card. Lastly I have upgraded my computer. Previously I had Gigabyte GA-Z170X-Gaming 3 mainboard and now I have Gigabyte Z690 UD AX. I have both those computers working (I've tested both computers with the same hard drive so there is no settings difference). When I plug the card on Z170X, it is working properly. But when I plug the card in Z690, it doesn't recognize it at all. Even it is not showing in BIOS (Plugged card list). What should I do in order to make the card work?

Answer (score 0):

After a reserarch I found out that setting PCIe speed from Auto to Gen1 is the solution. Otherwise card is not detected by BIOS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).